Function being L-smooth does not imply Lipschitz continuity of gradient
it is a standard argument that if a function is L-Smooth (i.e. locally bounded by a quadratic function: $f(y) \leq f(x) + <\nabla f(x),y-x> + \frac{L}{2}||y-x||^2$), differentiable and convex, then its gradient is L-Lipschitz.
However, this proof relies heavily on the fact that the function is convex, whereas the convex holds even if the function is not convex.
So my question is: is there a counterexample of a function that is L-smooth but with non L-Lipschitz gradient?

The definition of L-smoothness I know is independent of convexity. $f$ is L-smooth per definition if $||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \leq L ||x-y||,$ this is the same as the gradient being L-Lipschitz.

OK - however, i learned the definition i mentioned in the question. Ist there any function that is l-smooth by my definition but not by yours? i can Show that the definitions are equivalent if the function is convex.

The condition you provided is known as "descent lemma for L-smooth functions", see e.g. https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hf323/L23-III-OPT/lecture3.pdf. L-smoothness implies your condition, but the converse is generally not true.

I found an answer to this question myself:
Note the following equivalent definition of $L$-smoothness:
By looking at the definition of $L$-smoothness, one realizes that (my) definition is equivalent to the function $$g(x) = \frac{L}{2}||x||^2 - f(x)$$ being convex (the proof works using the first order characterisation of convexity).
Now, one can easily see that $f(x)=-x^4$ is $2$-smooth by this equivalent characterisation (as $x^2+x^4$ is convex).
Obviously, $f'(x)=-4x^3$ is not Lipschitz as its derivative is not bounded. Thus, this gives a counterexample to the mentioned impliciation if the function is not convex.

Hint: Every concave function is $0$-smooth (using your definition).

Thanks - in my definition I forgot to mention that $L>0$ for $L$-smoothness.
